Create server subscription for cups using IPP
I'm trying to create a server/system subscription for cups using IPP. According to their docs, it should be possible; however, I can't seem to get it to work, and I'm not finding anything online.
I could generate printer-subscription that look like this:
{
VERSION 2.0
OPERATION Create-Printer-Subscriptions

GROUP operation-attributes-tag
ATTR "attributes-charset" charset: utf-8
ATTR "attributes-natural-language" naturalLanguage: en-US
ATTR "printer-uri" uri: ipp://0.0.0.0:631/printers/PDF

GROUP subscription-attributes-tag
ATTR "notify-events" keyword: printer-modified,printer-added,printer-deleted
ATTR "notify-recipient-uri" uri: http://127.0.0.1:3333

}

However, when trying to use the create-system-subscription operation, it replaces printer-uri with system-uri and tells me I'm missing attributes.
{
    VERSION 2.0
    OPERATION Create-System-Subscriptions

    GROUP operation-attributes-tag
    ATTR "attributes-charset" charset: utf-8
    ATTR "attributes-natural-language" naturalLanguage: en-US
    ATTR "system-uri" uri: ipp://0.0.0.0:631/

    GROUP subscription-attributes-tag
    ATTR "notify-events" keyword: printer-added,printer-deleted,printer-modified
    ATTR "notify-recipient-uri" uri: rss://host.docker.internal:3333/
}


it seems cups handles this a bit different, for anyone wondering it is possible to achieve this by using the create-printer-subscription request and using "/" as the printer-uri
